# Hadoop lzopCodec pack

Tags: java, hadoop, lzo

I'm trying to create simple map-reduce example. 
Here's my code

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {        

    Job job = new Job();
    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(5);
    job.setJarByClass(Main.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, false);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Here's MyMapper

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(value, new LongWritable(1));
    }
}
```

And MyReducer

```
public class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
private MultipleOutputs<Text, LongWritable> mos;

@Override
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    long sum = 0;
    Iterator<LongWritable> iterator = values.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        sum += iterator.next().get();
    }
    mos.write(key, new LongWritable(sum), "Tabyretka");
}

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    super.setup(context);
    mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, LongWritable>(context);
}

@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    mos.close();
    }
}
```

When I run this program locally it work's ok! But when I load this program to another hadoop machine it give me next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
 not found.
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.<init>(CompressionCodecFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat.isSplitable(TextInputFormat.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:950)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:967)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:880)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:833)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1177)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:833)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:476)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:506)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:951)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:109)
... 27 more
```

But I don't use lzopCodec anywhere. I've tried disable using this codec by creating Configuration, setuping to it properties

```
conf.set("mapred.compress.map.output","false");
conf.set("mapred.output.compress","false");
```

and pass this configuration to job. But it still fails.

Does any one have a suggestion, why it tries to use lzopCodec and how can i disable it?

Comment: Which version of Hadoop are you using?

Comment: I'm using hadoop 0.20.2 version @Jackopo